# How to get rid of memcpy in QIoDevice

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qiodevice

I'm using Qt to make some audio output. There is an example audioouput, where pure virtual function qint64 QIODevice::readData ( char * data, qint64 maxSize ) is reimplemented like this(this is not actual code from example).

```
qint64 Generator::readData(char *data, qint64 len)
{
    memcpy(data, m_buffer.data(), len);
    return len;
}
```

So, we get pointer to data, copy memory from our buffer to this data. I'm wondering whether I can just assign pointer data to new location, like this:

```
qint64 Generator::readData(char *data, qint64 len)
{
    data = m_buffer.data();
    return len;
}
```

Because, memcpy is slow and C. So can I? Thank you!

OK, just not to receive comments "what is slow":
first - memcpy slower than pointer assignment
second - yes, I have latency in sound playing, I want to make program optimal at every point.

P.S. I'm trying to do it, and I have no sound, so maybe answer is no. Then why?

Comment: If using the C standard library offends you, there's always [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: _"memcpy is slow"_ have you actually profiled your code to determine it's "slow"?

Comment: Memcpy is slower than pointer assignment. And now there is some latency in program, I'm trying to make it superfast in every point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of this method only lets you return the data by copying them.
Assigning the pointer is pointless because this parameter is passed as a copy, so the assigned value won't be visible outside your method.

`memcpy` is not at all slow for realtime audio output (unless you are doing it on an 8-bit processor).

Too slow audio code can cause gaps in the sound but not latency. Latency is a result of a too big audio buffer.